# Python getopt (show command usage? think: Apache Commons CLI)

Tags: python

Using the Python getopt module, I can get a list of arguments and a list of
options, based on my definition of accepted short and long options. Using Java
and Apache Commons CLI, I can print a "usage" message with the printHelp method
of the HelpFormatter class based on the same definition, without having to write
any (trivial, time-consuming, exasperatingly boring to keep up-to-date) code for
it. Is there a similar facility to be leveraged in Python? I think it is **essential**!

PS I you haven't seen what HelpFormatter can do yet, check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the [`argparse` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) instead.

The `optparse` module has been deprecated in favour of that new and better module. The `argparse` module generates a helptext based on the options you give it.

If you are using a python version before 2.7, you can install the library as a separate dependency from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse).

Comment: I am on < 2.7... can I still use it?

Comment: @Robottinosino: Updated; the library is also available on older python versions.